# Access scale value in Vega

Tags: vega

I have a simple scale like this:

```
    {
        "name": "x",
        "type": "linear",
        "nice": true,
        "zero": true,
        "domain": {
            "data": "source",
            "field": "x"
        },
        "range": {
            "signal": "x_range"
        }
    }
```

How can I access the x-position for a value inside the domain?
I guessed I can do something like `scale('x')(10)` but that doesn't work. 
I know normally one can use `scale` and `value` to achieve the most but I would like to compute something based on the pixel value.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself:
Usage: `scale('x', 10)`

Documentation: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#scale